# angular 2 how to push multiple objects into array?

Tags: angular, typescript

**my result**
[image: my result]
**how to get**
[image: how to get]
first image is my console log result.

how to get the second image in angular 2 Push Method?

```
this.limitid = "0";
 this.userService.getTestUsers(this.limitid).subscribe(users => this.users = users);

this.limit = "12";
 this.userService.getTestUsers(this.limit).subscribe(usersnew => this.usersnew = usersnew);

this.users.push(this.usersnew[0]);

console.log(this.users);
```

the first index(11) objects is **this.users** results.

the index(12) objects is **this.usersnew** results.

my question is how to get the index(12) inside objects continues of  index(11) to  index(23)

image 1

Comment: btw: this is not specific to angular or typescript. It is javascript specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ES6 syntax **(short and simple)**:

```
this.users = [...this.users , ...this.usersnew];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.results = this.users.concat(this.usersnew);
```

Now your new array would be in this.results